# Server.MapPath VS. @Href("~/SomeFile.cshtml")

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have followed the tutorials over at MSDN and they all (from what I've seen) seem to use `@Href()` for URL's. E.g.

`<a href="@Href("~/")">Some link</a>` but I remember reading on here months ago that it is more secure to use Server.MapPath(), E.g.

`<a href="@Server.MapPath("~/")">Some link</a>` since it converts it to a full path, meaning that you cannot edit the underlying code to change where the form gets submitted to (or something like that). Is this true?

Should I use `Href()` or `Server.MapPath()`? Which one is better, and why?

Comment: I'll never use `Server.MapPath()` for URL path. As MSDN describes, the function(or even `Server` class) is to look for physical directory on your server.

Comment: Interesting. Another thought that I had was that it couldn't possibly be more secure in the way this person suggested; since all HTML source code can be viewed, so it doesn't matter whether or not you use Href or Server.MapPath - it'll still be viewable (and therefor editable via Dev tools)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More secure? I don't see a reason why - but I would use neither in Razor. Here's why:

As far as I remember, the `Href` function is from the ASP.NET 1.0 times. **When doing WebForms** (!) code you can just paste the ~-URL `<a href="~/" runat="server">Some link</a>`.

However, if you're doing ASP.NET **MVC** (which I assume you're doing since you're using Razor) you should rather use `Url.Content()` which fits with `Url.Action()` name-wise.